# Get index of the column with max value in everyrow without (...,) pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I worked this on my Jupyter.
I'd like to know if there's a way to find the location **(column index)** of the *max value in everyrow* in the table.
For example, it looks like this:

```
yo1 = [1,3,7]
yo2 = [2,4,5,6,8]
yo3 = [0.1,0.3,0.7]
yo4 = [0.2,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8]

yoo = []
for x in yo3:
    vvv = []
    for y in yo4:
        dot = x*y
        na = x+x
        nb = y+y
        prod = dot/(na+nb)
        vvv.append(prod)
    yoo.append(vvv)
yooo = pd.DataFrame(yoo, columns=(yo2), index=[yo1])
print(yooo)
```

(yes, it is cosine similarity)

```
output:
      2         4         5         6         8
1  0.033333  0.040000  0.041667  0.042857  0.044444
3  0.060000  0.085714  0.093750  0.100000  0.109091
7  0.077778  0.127273  0.145833  0.161538  0.186667
```

Then, I want to get **index** of the column with max value in everyrow. I used this :

```
go = yooo.idxmax().reset_index()
go.columns=['column', 'get']
go

output:
    column  get
0   2       (7,)
1   4       (7,)
2   5       (7,)
3   6       (7,)
4   8       (7,)
```

but my **desired output** is :

```
output:
    column  get
0   2       7
1   4       7
2   5       7
3   6       7
4   8       7
```

I've tried replace the '(' with ' '

```
go['get']=go['get'].str.replace('(','')
```

and used lstrip-rstrip

```
go['get']=go['get'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('(').rstrip(',)'))
```

also this one

```
top_n=1
get = pd.DataFrame({n: yooo[col].nlargest(top_n).index.tolist() for n, col in enumerate(yooo)}).T
```

They all did'nt work well :(

Help me.. How to solve this and would you explain it to me??? Thankyou!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your real problem is in your dataframe constructor for 'yooo', you are wrapping a list with [] creating a 2d list and thus creating a pd.MultiIndex, hence the tuples (7,).  Use this instead:

```
 yooo = pd.DataFrame(yoo, columns=(yo2), index=yo1)

 yooo.idxmax()
```

Output:

```
2    7
4    7
5    7
6    7
8    7
dtype: int64
```

And further to get dataframe with column names:

```
yooo.idxmax().rename_axis('column').rename('get').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   column  get
0       2    7
1       4    7
2       5    7
3       6    7
4       8    7
```

Comment: Yes.. Thank you very much. You save my life :D That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @VFWilmay if te answer helped , please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#52350) the answer so as to close the question. Thanks